# Create Table Every X Rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a SQL Table that we are selling off some of the data, so I need a quick way of splitting the main table into sub tables every 50 rows.  Table nomenclature does not matter, I am just stuck on a way of selecting 50 different rows for each table with the table not holding a primary key or numeric field.

How would one go about this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: You added some details in comments below that would be very helpful in describing your situation. You should add that information to your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you can change the original table:

- Alter original table, adding new column `batch_id` (default NULL).
- Run the following

  ```
  DECLARE @rowCount int = 1
         ,@batchId  int = 1
  ;        

  WHILE @rowCount > 0
  BEGIN
      UPDATE TOP (50) myTable
         SET batch_id = @batchId
       WHERE batch_id IS NULL
      ;
      SELECT @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
            ,@batch_id = @batch_id + 1
      ;
  END;
  ```
- Then, simply create new tables `myTable_batch_x`, where *x* is 1 through `@batchId - 1`, and assigned records based on the stored batch IDs.

If you can't modify the original table, but have space to make a copy of it, create a copy with the new column, and proceed as above.

---

Alternately: add a `my_row_id` column (integer) to the original table, as an `IDENTITY` column:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
  ADD COLUMN my_row_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL;
```

This will create the new column, and automatically populate it with sequential integers starting from one.

Using the new value, assign rows to batches (1-50, 51-100, etc.). To get the rows that go into a given batch:

```
SELECT *  -- or, actual column list - you can exclude my_row_id that way
  FROM myTable
 WHERE (((my_row_id - 1) / 50) + 1) = @batch_no
;
```

Since `my_row_id` is an integer, if we divide it by another integer any fractional result will be dropped. So, `0/50` = 0, ..., `49/50` = 0, `50/50` = 1, .... To include `my_row_id` = 50 in batch 1, we simply subtract 1 from `my_row_id`. And, to start with `batch_no` 1 instead of 0, we add one to get our `batch_no`.

NOTE: As noted in the comments, you can simplify the code slightly. If you use `IDENTITY(50,0)` when adding `my_row_id`, then the WHERE clause could be:

```
 WHERE (my_row_id / 50) = @batch_no
```

The first 50 rows would be numbered 50-99, and this equation would evaluate to `1` for them; for the next fifty rows (100-149), it evaluates to `2`; and so on.

Comment: Just a suggestion on the IDENTITY option - you could simplify your logic by declaring my_row_id as IDENTITY(0, 1). Then you wouldn't need to offset by 1 in your calculation, and you'd still end up with fifty rows in your first batch.

Comment: Good point = as long as `my_row_id` is considered disposable, we don't really need to start it at 1. In fact, `IDENTITY(50,1)` would simplify thing even more.

Answer (score 0):

If it were greater amounts, I would have recommended partitions or something like that.

Since It's a small amount, I'd have one "Holding" Table that the records get created on (up to 50).

```
1) Records created into Holding table
2) @ 50 crecords in Holding table, Create new Historical Table 
    [Table_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS]
2.5) Insert Records from Holding Table into newly created table
3) TRUNCATE Holding Table
4) ???
5) ProFit
```

I'd recommend creating the table name with a variable, so that you can use the same variable over and over.

Honestly I'm not really "for" this approach at all.  Seems like too many tables and it would be difficult to manage.  If it were me I'd keep it all in one table and have something like a BATCHID to separate the batches of 50 records.

Comment: I have full control over the SQL Table and could alter the table to update every 50 records to assign batch1, batch2, etc....just not sure of how to do such w/o having a numeric field in the table to use for the counter

Comment: Why can't use use a numeric field like INT or BIGINT?  The procedure that Inserts would just check the MAX(BATCHID) and increment it by 1, right?

Comment: But how would I "group" the records from my holding table in batches of 50?

Comment: The holding tablewould have a max of 50 records.  Every single record in the table would belong to the same BatchID when it gets pushed to History.  Once they push to history, the Holding table gets truncated.

Comment: That is where my confusion is coming from.  I have a table already that holds roughly 2,000 records.  How do I batch the records in groups of 50 to push to the holding table then?

Comment: The holding table would act as a staging table.  Like Filling a cup (holding table) from the sink and then using that cup to fill a bucket.  When the cup gets full (50 records), you mark it with a BATCHID and dump the contents into the bucket (Historical table).  This process would empty (Truncate) the cup (holding table).

Comment: I still do not follow...

Comment: Records are initially created into the holding table.  When the holding table reaches 50, it is dumped into the historical table with a new BatchID.

Comment: I think the question is: once you've pulled 50 records from `SourceTable` into the holding table and written them out, how do you avoid having any of those records from `SourceTable` show up in the second, third, fourth, etc. batches? Is there an outer cursor loop, writing individual records from `SourceTable` into the holding table one by one?

Comment: Good call!  I'd probably use a MERGE or cursor loop to only add them if they don't exist.